# How can I set taxonomy programmatically

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, save-post

Here is my situation.  I plan to distribute a theme I am working on and it has a custom post type called `Code` and it has a custom taxonomy called `Languages` now I also use a custom metabox with a dropdown list of available languages,  I need to somehow make the value that they choose in the select dropdown box to not only save as the meta value (which it does already) but I need that value to also be picked as the taxonomy for that post

So If they make a post and pick the Language "PHP" in the meta_box, then when they post, it will make the "PHP" taxonomy be selected.  I plan to hide the taxonomy UI and auto populate all the possible taxonomy terms

1) How can I make a metabox value be saved in addition to a meta_value but also as the taxonomy for that post?

### Update

Ok I have found a possible solution,`wp_set_object_terms( 123, 'PHP', 'tag' );` will add a PHP tag taxonomy to post ID 123.

So I just need to know how to get a post ID when it is being posted, is that even possible as the post is not in the DB yet on a new post?  Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hook your actions to the `save_post` hook. It fires right after the post is created and the `$post_id` and other `$post` data variables are already available.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'jason_code_save_post', 10, 2 );

function jason_code_save_post( $post_ID, $post ) {

     if ( 'code' != $post->post_type || wp_is_post_revision( $post_ID ) )
          return;

     wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, 'PHP', 'tag' );

}
```

See [Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).

Let me know if something needs more explanation...